# Why am I getting an error saying "<variable> might not have been initialized"?

Tags: java

> This program will create an array of 10 integers. Each element in the array is initialized to 2. Each element of the array is then added up to get a total for the entire array. The answer we are expecting is 20. See if you can correct the following code to produce the correct solution.

How come I get an error saying that `sum` might not have been initialized even if i did it in the `for` loop?

```
public class WarmUp_01_22_2014{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int[] myArray = new int[12];
     int total=0;

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         myArray[i] = 2;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
         int sum = 0;
         int sum += myArray[i];
     }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in the array is " + sum);
 }
}//end class WarmUp_01_22_2014
```

Comment: You need to declare it outside the loop.

Comment: And remove the word `int` from before `sum += myArray[i];`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't getting that message with that code; this won't compile because `sum` isn't visible to `println`. Most likely, you have a declaration of an `int sum` in the `main` body, and then you declare another `int sum` inside the loop. You only want to "create" the variable once, and then just assign values to it.

I suspect that you're really using `total` in your program; just change your second `for` loop to this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
     total += myArray[i]; // the variable "total" was created and set to zero above
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WarmUp_01_22_2014{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 int[] myArray = new int[12];
 int total=0;
 int sum = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     myArray[i] = 2;
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

     sum += myArray[i];
 }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in the array is " + sum);
 }
}//end class WarmUp_01_22_2014
```

Should work. Declare your variable higher up so it can be accessed by the println() method.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- an array of size **10 integers** means that you need to write `new int[10]` instead of `new int[12]`
- you declared `sum` *inside* of the for loop, so it is not accessible outside of that for loop (because there is no guarantee that it will even be declared).
- you are also redeclaring `sum` in every loop by writing `int sum += myArray[i]` - only declare once
- `i < 12` and `i < 10` can be changed to be `i < myArray.length` to make it more general.

---

```
public class WarmUp_01_22_2014{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] myArray = new int[10]; // size 10, not 12
        int sum = 0; // declare sum here

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ // < myArray.length
            myArray[i] = 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ // < myArray.length
            sum += myArray[i]; // add on to the sum, don't declare it here
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in the array is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to solve the problem

A simple adjustment such as (i) bringing the declaration before entering the loop and (ii) changing the value type (`int`) when using variable `sum` the second time to avoid conflict will do the trick:

```
public class WarmUp_01_22_2014{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = new int[12];
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myArray[i] = 2;
    }

    //declare varaible here to avoid error
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        //change int sum+=myArray[i] to sum+=myArray[i]
        sum += myArray[i];

    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in the array is " + sum);

}
}
```

### Reasoning

When the compiler compiles the source code, it still doesn't know that a variable such as `sum` does exists. According to the compiler, the variable `sum` is created only if the `for` loop is activated (which we as humans know is inevitable but the machine doesn't).